# Test of Pentominoes

Tags: geometry, computer-puzzle, polyomino

> These are pentominoes, with letter codes:
>
> [image]
>
> **Create 4 yes/no questions which uniquely classify each pentomino.**
>
> Examples of such questions are:
>
> - Does it have rotational symmetry?
> - Does it have reflection symmetry?
> - Is it the net of an open box?
> - Does it have point symmetry?
>
> The idea is to create a set of questions where **no pentomino has the same answers as another.**

Source: https://www.mathsisfun.com/pentomino_challenge.html

Comment: A bit irritating that they used some non-standard letter designations (M instead of W, N instead of S or Z, and Z instead of N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my first go:

1. Does it fit (perpendicularly) inside a rectangle smaller than 9 squares of area?
2. Is there a square with more than 2 neighbours?
3. Can you rotate the mirror image of the piece back to the original?
4. Find the longest straight run that isn't a dead end at both ends. Is it exactly three squares long?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this kind of reasoning is allowed, but:

> this seems trivial if we can simply refer to the letter labels themselves.  e.g. four questions could be:

> Q1: Is the letter in TUVXYZ?

> Q2: Is the letter in FILTUV?

> Q3: Is the letter in LMNUVX?

> Q4: Is the letter in MFVY?

Each pentomino will have a unique set of answers to those four questions.

Comment: There was a comment similar like this, using rows and columns. But it was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer:

> ```
>                                        U:      P:      N:
>                                        ┌┬┐     ┌┬┐     ┌┐
>                                        ├┼┘     ├┼┤     ├┼┐
>                                        ├┼┐     ├┼┘     └┼┤
>                                        └┴┘     └┘       ├┤
>                                                         └┘
>
>
>      square bbox:                      False   False   False
>      cut from ∞ "+":                   False   False   False
>      simultaneously sort x and y:      False   False   True
>      connect □ centres w/o leaving:    False   True    False
>
>
>
>
>                                        Y:      L:      I:
>                                        ┌┐      ┌┬┐     ┌┐
>                                        ├┼┐     ├┼┘     ├┤
>                                        ├┼┘     ├┤      ├┤
>                                        ├┤      ├┤      ├┤
>                                        └┘      └┘      ├┤
>                                                        └┘
>      square bbox:                      False   False   False
>      cut from ∞ "+":                   True    True    True
>      simultaneously sort x and y:      False   True    True
>      connect □ centres w/o leaving:    False   False   True
>
>
>
>
>                                        F:      Z:      W:
>                                        ┌┬┐     ┌┬┐     ┌┬┐
>                                        └┼┼┐    └┼┤     └┼┼┐
>                                         ├┼┘     ├┼┐     └┼┤
>                                         └┘      └┴┘      └┘
>
>
>
>
>      square bbox:                      True    True    True
>      cut from ∞ "+":                   False   False   False
>      simultaneously sort x and y:      False   True    True
>      connect □ centres w/o leaving:    False   False   True
>
>
>
>
>                                        T:      X:      V:
>                                        ┌┬┬┐     ┌┐     ┌┬┬┐
>                                        └┼┼┘    ┌┼┼┐    ├┼┴┘
>                                         ├┤     └┼┼┘    ├┤
>                                         └┘      └┘     └┘
>
>
>
>
>      square bbox:                      True    True    True
>      cut from ∞ "+":                   True    True    True
>      simultaneously sort x and y:      False   False   True
>      connect □ centres w/o leaving:    False   True    False
> ```